# How shall I draw "K" plot by matplotlib.finance for some special formate data as below?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The codes are as below:

```
import tushare as ts
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc as candle
stock=ts.get_hist_data('000581',ktype='w')
```

the data form of "stock" is as below picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo7QU.png)

Then the below codes:

```
vals=stock.iloc[:,0:4]
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
candle(ax,vals)
```

I get error as below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/finance.py", line 735, in candlestick_ohlc
    alpha=alpha, ochl=False)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/finance.py", line 783, in _candlestick
t, open, high, low, close = q[:5]
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)

How shall I resove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`candlestick` needs a very specific format *and* order to work. For example, if you use `_ohlc`, then the order must be open-high-low-close. The array for the candlestick graph can be prepared as follows:

```
candleArray = []
while i < len(datep):
    newLine = datep[i], openp[i], highp[i], lowp[i], closep[i], volumep[i], pricechange[i], pchange[i]
    candleArray.append(newLine)
    i += 1
```

Then, you can call candlestick with the array `candleArray`.

Comment: Thanks for you help; what is the meaning of  "pricechange[i], pchange[i]" and in addition, how shall I know the details about "candlestick"

Comment: These two columns I adapted from your data. `pricechange` [close-open] and `pchange` [(close/open-1)*100] won't go into the candlestick, so, you can also skip these columns. I can recommend [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5Dn1HjBPA4), which is actually part of a whole series. Depending on the graphing interface and version you are using, there might be minor differences in the use of `ohlc`. To look at the code of `ohlc`, you can open the file `finance.py`, which is normally located in `Lib\site-packages\matplotlib`.

Comment: Thank you very much; I know this time.